# Confirmation Dialog On Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to add a confirmation dialog in my telerik rad grid but I am having issues. It's causing the eventpagevaldition error to crop up. I have the following RadGrid and when I set it to true its not deleting the row so I don't know what is wrong.  Can someone help?

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdSoccerPlayers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   DataSourceID="entyPlayer" GroupPanelPosition="Top" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" OnItemCommand="grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="Both" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True">
    <MasterTableView DataSourceID="entyPlayer"   CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="id">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="player_id" FilterControlAltText="Filter player_id column" HeaderText="player_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="player_id" UniqueName="player_id">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fname" FilterControlAltText="Filter fname column" HeaderText="fname" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="fname" UniqueName="fname">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lname" FilterControlAltText="Filter lname column" HeaderText="lname" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="lname" UniqueName="lname">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>



             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="telephone" FilterControlAltText="Filter telephone column" HeaderText="telephone" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="telephone" UniqueName="telephone">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" FilterControlAltText="Filter email column" HeaderText="email" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="email" UniqueName="email">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="active" DataType="System.Boolean" FilterControlAltText="Filter active column" HeaderText="active" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="active" UniqueName="active">
            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="createdDate" FilterControlAltText="Filter createdDate column" HeaderText="createdDate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="createdDate" UniqueName="createdDate" DataType="System.DateTime">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="author" FilterControlAltText="Filter author column" HeaderText="author" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="author" UniqueName="author">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="siteid" FilterControlAltText="Filter siteid column" HeaderText="siteid" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="siteid" UniqueName="siteid" DataType="System.Guid">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="gender" FilterControlAltText="Filter gender column" HeaderText="gender" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="gender" UniqueName="gender">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter id column" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" UniqueName="id">
             </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

           <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"   UniqueName="Delete"
 ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="~/Icons/delete.png" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true"
 ConfirmTitle="Delete" ConfirmDialogType="Classic"  
 ConfirmText="Are you sure want to delete the selected report?" />

        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid><telerik:RadWindow ID="rdConfim" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindow>
```

Then in my code behind it's the following

```
 protected void grdSoccerPlayers_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {

            Guid strId = Guid.Empty;
            Response.Redirect("edit.aspx?id=" + strId.ToString());

        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString()); 
            Response.Redirect("edit.aspx?id=" + strId.ToString());
        }
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {
            Response.Redirect("edit.aspx");

        }

        if(e.CommandName ==RadGrid.DeleteCommandName)
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

            player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);

            _dal.SoccerEntities.players.DeleteObject(_player);

            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
            grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();

        }


    }
```

But it's not deleting the row at all - it's staying in memeory. I must add when I click the autogen one it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Call `grdSoccerPlayers.Rebind();` method. This will have the grid request its data from the data source again. The `DataBind` method has very limited use.